# How to implement advertise in roku using Scene Graph

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working bright script using scene graph. I want to play ads before video play. How to implement in bright script using scene graph.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, RAF does not (yet?) have native SceneGraph integration, so you have to jump through a few hoops to get it working

For more, check 
https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=95688#p536636

PS. this was the case in **2016**. Since 2017, Roku's RAF supports RSG mode natively.

Answer (score 1):

Roku provided a framework called Roku Advertising Framework (RAF), current version is 1.7.

But this version is not fully supporting Scene Graph. If you want to insert ad into Scene Graph application, you need to contact Roku to get the RAF2.0 Beta version.

And the Product Version would release recently.

Hope this helps.